# How do I apply a COUNT() column (calculated for each row) without making my run in O(n^2)

Tags: sql, t-sql, soql

I have a "clicks" table that records every time a user clicks on a link.

For the purpose of keeping this simple, let's just assume this table only has three columns "Email", "LinkId", and "ClickTime".

My issue is I need to add a calculated column to my SELECT query. This column will record a true or false value indicating whether the system considers the click valid or not.

An entry in the table will be considered invalid if there exist two or more entries in the table which share the same domain name (taken from the email address), "LinkId" and "ClickTime".

I am trying to extract every record in this table with an extra column titled "valid" that has a true or false value in it according to the specification above.

Below is my attempt but it's not working and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(cl1.Email, LEN(cl1.Email) - CHARINDEX('@', cl1.Email)) Domain,
    IF (SELECT 
        COUNT (*) 
    FROM 
        clicks as cl2
    WHERE
        cl2.ClickTime = cl1.ClickTime AND
        cl2.Email LIKE CONCAT(cl1.Domain,"@%") AND
        cl2.LinkId = cl1.LinkId
    ) <= 3 (True) ELSE (False) 
    As Valid
FROM 
    clicks as cl1
WHERE
```

Comment: which sql version? i think that's `mysql`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu it needs to work in T-SQL...In the past I've done some bits and pieces in MySQL so I may have used some incorrect syntax above. Sorry

Comment: obviously you got the wrong syntax for `concat` and `if`

Comment: what you can do is jump to `rextester.com` or `sqlfiddle.com` and muck up some data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple `GROUP BY` provide what you want?

Here is a simple example to illustrate it:

```
with rte as 
(
 select email, linkid, clicktime, count(*) as num
 from table1
 group by  email, linkid, clicktime
 having count(*) > 2
 )
 select * from rte
```

Example code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdaab/2